# How can I get data from response body?

Tags: android, kotlin, okhttp

I need to get `"status"` value from my response. I tried `JSONObject` but it gave that *java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException* error in the code below. I need that because I make some process with status value like start new activity etc. How can I get this?

```
private fun doReq(){
    val client = OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
        .build()
    val mediaType = "application/json;charset=utf-8".toMediaTypeOrNull()
    val body: RequestBody = jsonSended.toRequestBody(mediaType)
    val request: Request = Request.Builder()
        .url("https://apiapiapi/auth")
        .method("POST", body)
        .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .addHeader("Authorization", "$authValue")
        .addHeader("x-iyzi-rnd", "$randomString")
        .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
        .build()

    val response = client.newCall(request).execute()
    println(response.body?.string())  // I CAN GET RESPONSE BODY 

    var json = JSONObject(response.body.toString())
    var status = json.getString("status")  // HERE NOT WORKING...

    println(status)


}
```

In the response when server return failure : `{"status":"failure","errorCode":"12","errorMessage":"invalid","locale":"tr","systemTime":1610022545347,"conversationId":"123412341234"}`

If server return valid my response is very very long but it also have status so I can get that status value and do something with that. Is that correct way to do it? I need advice.

Comment: I would recommend using Retrofit for that. You can find many resources online on how to use it.

Comment: @SebastianM I already did with okhttp so I don't want to change it again. Is there any way to do it with this code?

Comment: It wouldn't make sense to keep this code if you would use Retrofit.

Answer (score 0):

Use response.response or make request in try catch block statement, it will solve the problem

Comment: How can I use response.response. Can you add some sample?

Comment: In react native it will be like this
```
axios
    .get('crawler/assignment')
    .then((data) => {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ASSIGNMENT_RECORD,
        payload: data.data,
      });
    }) .catch((err) => {
      if (err.response) {
        console.log(err.response.data);
        console.log(err.response.status);
        console.log(err.response.headers);
      } else if (err.request) {
           console.log(err.request);
      } else {
        console.log('Error', err.message);
      }
      console.log(err.config);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
private fun doReq(){
  try {
    var errorResponce: ErrorResponce? = null
    val client = OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
        .build()
    val mediaType = "application/json;charset=utf-8".toMediaTypeOrNull()
    val body: RequestBody = jsonSended.toRequestBody(mediaType)
    val request: Request = Request.Builder()
        .url("https://apiapiapi/auth")
        .method("POST", body)
        .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .addHeader("Authorization", "$authValue")
        .addHeader("x-iyzi-rnd", "$randomString")
        .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
        .build()

    val response = client.newCall(request).execute()
    println(response.body?.string())  // I CAN GET RESPONSE BODY
    if (response.errorBody() != null) {
         errorResponce = conversorDeErro.convert(response.errorBody()!!)
    }
  }
  catch (e: IOException) {
    println(e);

  }
  finally {
    return errorResponce;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read response.body?.string() exactly once and store the result.

```
    val response = client.newCall(request).execute()
    println(response.body?.string())  // This permanently consumes the output, you should store the result 

    var json = JSONObject(response.body.toString()) // toString() is not the response body, it is a debug representation of the response body
    var status = json.getString("status")
```